# Getting the ID of a boost::thread for PostThreadMessage

Tags: c++, windows, boost, boost-thread

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C++ project using Boost 1.47.0 where I need to get the native Windows ID of a boost::thread to pass to PostThreadMessage.

In Windows Vista and 7, I would just do this:

```
DWORD thread_id = ::GetThreadId( mythread.native_handle() );
```

This is fine, but I also need my app to work in XP where `GetThreadId` does not exist.

I have found that boost:thread stores the thread ID value in boost::thread::id's private data member `thread_data`. I can get to that by doing some nasty casts:

```
boost::detail::thread_data_base* tdb = *reinterpret_cast< boost::detail::thread_data_base** >( &message_thread.get_id() );
DWORD thread_id = tdb->id;
```

But, I start getting compiler warnings for referencing a temporary `boost::thread::id` object.

```
warning C4238: nonstandard extension used : class rvalue used as lvalue
```

Is there a good way to get the ID? It is very frustrating to see the piece of data I need, but not be able to get at it.

Thanks,
PaulH

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a clever/nasty hack using a technique described by [Johannes Schaub - litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb) on his blog, [Access to private members: Safer nastiness](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html).  All credit should go to Johannes.  I'll take the blame for applying it to a real-world scenario (or maybe you can):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "boost/thread.hpp"

using namespace std;


// technique for accessing private class members
//
//  from: http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2011/12/access-to-private-members-safer.html
//

template<typename Tag, typename Tag::type M>
struct Rob { 
  friend typename Tag::type get(Tag) {
    return M;
  }
};

struct thread_data_f {
    typedef unsigned boost::detail::thread_data_base::*type;

    friend type get(thread_data_f);
};

struct thread_id_f {
    typedef boost::detail::thread_data_ptr boost::thread::id::*type;

    friend type get(thread_id_f);
};

template struct Rob<thread_data_f, &boost::detail::thread_data_base::id>;
template struct Rob<thread_id_f, &boost::thread::id::thread_data>;

unsigned int get_native_thread_id( boost::thread const& t)
{
    boost::detail::thread_data_ptr thread_data = t.get_id().*get(thread_id_f());
    unsigned thread_id = (*thread_data).*get(thread_data_f());

    return thread_id;
}

//
//
//


// test of get_native_thread_id()


void thread_func()
{
    cout << "thread running..." << endl;

    cout << "Windows says my ID is: " << GetCurrentThreadId() << endl;

    for (;;) {
        boost::this_thread::yield();
    }
}


int main()
{
    boost::thread t(thread_func);

    ::Sleep(2000);

    cout << "boost says my thread ID is: " << get_native_thread_id(t) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure if this qualifies as a "good way" to get the info.  But it works without modifying the boost headers or libraries, and the compiler doesn't complain at all - even with relatively high warnings. Tested on:

- MinGW 4.6.1  `-Wall -Wextra` with a few especially noisy warnings turned off - but not for this test in particular. They're turned off in my generic 'compile this test' script.
- VC++ 2008 and 2010 with /W4

Here a sample run that shows it works:

```
C:\temp>test
thread running...
Windows says my ID is: 5388
boost says my thread ID is: 5388
```

Of course, it should go without saying that this might break if/when boost::thread changes over time, but probably not silently.

---

Some explanatory notes/pointers:

The 'loophole' used in this technique is in C++03 14.7.2/8 "Explicit instantiation":

> The usual access checking rules do not apply to names used to specify
>   explicit instantiations.  [Note: In particular, the template arguments
>   and names used in the function declarator (including parameter types,
>   return types and exception specifications) may be private types or
>   objects which would normally not be accessible and the template may be
>   a member template or member function which would not normally be
>   accessible.]

Dave Abrahams has a 'gist' that uses similar techniques along with comments that explain pretty nicely what's going on:

- https://gist.github.com/1528856

I found that in a comment he left on a previous article about private member access on Johannes' blog: [Access to private members. That's easy!](http://bloglitb.blogspot.com/2010/07/access-to-private-members-thats-easy.html)

Comment: That is the coolest thing I've seen today. I'll waste the next 3 hours trying to understand it. Thanks!